# The command does not work until the http server is turned off

Tags: json, node.js, http, npm, server

I have a **"server" folder** in which I installed a npm package.json file and http server, and there is also a  **"webdir" folder** with a web page (inside the **"server" folder**).

I wrote a command `npm start` in npm **package.json** file, that makes 3 things:

1. Go to the folder with the web page: `cd webdir`
2. Start the http server :  `node ../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`
3. Open a web page: `open http:localhost:8080`

Final code:
 `"start": "cd webdir && node ../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server && open http:localhost:8080"`

I encountered a problem: if I write these three commands in sequence in **package.json** file using **&&** or **semicolon**, the third command is not executed until I manually stop the server. Apparently the command to start the server remains incomplete until the server is turned off.

How can I avoid it?

I work on Imac (Mac OS EL Capitan)

Comment: It keeps running because the server keeps running. You could try exchanging the second and third command (perhaps starting the server is a bit faster than your browser opening the page).

Comment: @robertklep I tried it, it does not work. I get a page that is not loaded (standard page load error) and I need to manually refresh it. If I do it again after it - I get something like the cached version of the page (if I made changes in it before starting the server, they do not appear until I manually refresh the page)

Comment: In that case, you need to start the server in the background, so the rest of the commands will continue to run. However, that's not ideal because it will keep the server running _after_ `npm` has already stopped.

Comment: You could use child_process.  See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options and more specifically for your case http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn

Comment: @robertklep How can I do it? I need to make server started and the page opened on the "npm start" command...

Comment: @Wake Thank you for the information! How should look the code for the "npm start" command in this case? I'm new to the NPM and JSON...

Comment: If you want to follow what was done in the second link, you'd be creating a new node module (they called it script.js) to launch you http-server.js as a child process.  Then you would just change your step 2 to run that node module in place of http-server.  The thing I'm wondering is whether you'd have to add some kind of wait after it's invocation to ensure the web server is up and running before you reach step 3.

Comment: @Wake Thank you for the clarification, I will try this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `http-server` will run indefinitely, until you (manually) stop it. Only after it has stopped will the following command (`open ...`) be executed, which is too late.

A solution is to start the HTTP server in the background. Because this may cause problems (the HTTP server will keep running even after `npm` exits), you have to also wait for its exit using the shell's `wait` command:

```
"start": "cd webdir && node ../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server & open http://localhost:8080 ; wait"
```

Notice that between `http-server` and `open` is a *single* ampersand. This backgrounds the `http-server` process.

Depending on how fast the server starts, you may still get an error page in the browser (when the browser requests the page before the server has fully started). To work around this, you need to add a `sleep 3;` (meaning *"sleep 3 seconds"*) between the single ampersand and `open`:

```
cd webdir && node ../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server & sleep 3; open http:localhost:8080 ; wait
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's almost exactly what I need! If I start the server using the command "start" it works. But if I then stop the server and close the page, change the CSS and use "npm start" command again - I will see the page as it was before the CSS changes, and I have to refresh the page manually to see them.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin to be honest, I don't think that you can prevent that: the browser will initially probably use a cached version of the CSS. However, perhaps you should look into [`watch-http-server`](https://github.com/gstack/watch-http-server), which would allow to keep the server running and automatically reload the page when any file changes are made.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will study this method. But, apart from this problem this command does exactly what I need, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```
"start": "(start /d webdir node ../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server) & (open http:localhost:8080)"
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, after executing the command, the standart blank web page with an error message opened, and this message in the console: http://prnt.sc/c5a4qv

Comment: Ooo, you have iMac/iOS. It's decision for Windows.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll mention it in the question.